# What is an efficient way to keep track of a small number of struct types by int id in c++?

Tags: c++, optimization

I have about 70-150 different structs X with an unsigned integral ID field. They are read in and initialized on initialization of program and never modified thereafter. What would be the fastest way to access them (which happens a lot) among the following (or some other method?):

1. Use a std::vector v; where v[X.id] = X; to access by doing X& x = v[id]; (this should do a copy at the beginning but later on merely do a lookup by id on essentially a flat array.
2. Same as above but std::vector v; with X* x = v[id]; I am wary about this one because it has one extra level of indirection.
3. a std::map - feels like overkill compared to above?
4. same as above but unordered_map - again given 70-150 occurrences might not even beat suggestion 3.
5. Anything more clever? One problem I see with 1 is it might be a bit sparse in access patterns but not sure how to address that if that's the fastest way.

Comment: Encapsulate the storage so that you can easily swap out different implementations.  Then implement #1, because it is likely to perform sufficiently well.  If it doesn't, look for alternatives.  Because you'll have encapsulated the storage, trying out other alternatives will be easy.

Comment: Do the simplest thing that could possibly work and optimize it only if  you can prove that it's a bottleneck. That said, I guess in this case it'd quite hard to beat #1 and #2.

Comment: hash the id into a small range (say 0-100) and store it as array of linked list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using vector will be definitely the fastest approach:

- Vector has complexity O(1).  No need to search or hash, you will immediately find your instance.
- Map has complexity O(log N).  The map needs to compare your index with logN other entries to find your instance.
- Unordered_map has complexity O(1), but with quite some overhead of calculating the hash value (although for simple numbers it will be not that much).  However, the std::unordered_map still puts multiple entries behind one hash-index, so instead of comparing one index, it has to compare several ones (I think by default it's 4).

Answer (score 2):

I think that for a small number of items there is no faster way to access than using array or vector data types because it provides constant time access. In case of many objects this approach is also fastest but also the most memory expensive.

Comment: Indeed vector is the fastest, but in many cases also uses the least memory (unless the range of used ID's has many holes (sparse)).  Map and unordered_map have quite some overhead to store their internal data structures.  In practice you can have many empty entries in the vector before you start to take more memory than a map or unordered_map.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind pre-allocating the space for all the structures in advance, and the IDs can be ordered sequentially so they are also indexes, just use approach 1.

If the structures are expensive to construct, delay construction either by not actually placing the construction code in the default constructor (and doing it explicitly via a method call later) or by using a raw array and [placement new](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax) on memory "slots" within that array.

If IDs are not sequential, use `std::unordered_map` to prevent waste of space on "holes".